# Navigation Left Bar Button Item as Image Logo

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add an image to a left on a Navigation Bar using `leftBarButtonItem` that will serve as a small logo. I'm able to add the image perfectly fine. My question is how do I disable it from being clickable and just keep the same state so it doesn't turn gray when someone presses it. I just want it as an image in the left of the Navigation Bar. Below is what I use to add the logo to the left of the navigation bar. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
        let btnName = UIButton()
        btnName.setImage(UIImage(named: "NavIcon"), forState: .Normal)
        btnName.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 50)

        let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        leftBarButton.customView = btnName
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
```

Comment: You may change the userInteractionEnabled to false?

Comment: If you don't want it to act like a button, why are you using `UIButton`? Just use `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
btnName.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked! I didn't realize that this would work on just the button and not the entire Nav Bar. Thank you very much

Comment: This is kind of silly. If you don't want the button to act like a button, don't use a button. Use a `UIImageView` instead of `UIButton`.